# in selenium webdriver while writing code for to take screeshot getting this error

Tags: java, file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method copyFile(java.io.File, java.io.File) in the type FileUtils is not applicable for the arguments (java.io.File, com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File)
The constructor File(String) is not visible

at DEMO.Screenshot.Homepage(Screenshot.java:37)
at DEMO.Screenshot.main(Screenshot.java:47)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
package DEMO;

import java.io.IOException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

public class Screenshot {

WebDriver driver;

public void Homepage() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\selenium_course\\geckodriver.exe");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    // driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://amazon.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    // take screen shot and store into variable

    java.io.File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // copy screen shot into local system

    try {

        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("E:\\selenium_course\\Screen\\homepage.png"));
    } catch (IOException t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    }
    driver.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Screenshot s = new Screenshot();
    s.Homepage();

}
```

}

Comment: So that means that you're passing the wrong type of argument to copyFile. Can you pass it a normal java.io.File instead? Can you show us the code you've written that's causing this exception please?

Comment: done still getting error

Answer (score 1):

You use `File` from `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file`, you should use `File` from `java.io`. Replace the import

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;
```

With

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: You're telling us you've removed all references to `com.gargoylesoft` from your Java source file and you're still getting an error about com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File?

Answer (score 0):

//instead of using try catch at 
             FILEUTIL.cpy file use that exception handler at public static void main//
     public static void main(String[] args) throws exception

Comment: That depends on what he's trying to do with the exception though, and would skip the driver.close() on exception, and wouldn't solve the compilation error anyway.